# Azure Pipelines trigger by pipeline completion runs on wrong branch

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a yaml pipeline "PipelineA" that does a scheduled nightly build for specific branches. This I set up in the pipeline trigger settings in DevOps using a schedule and branch filters.

- master
- release/v1.0

This works well. Each night, I get two builds started, one for each branch.

Then I have a downstream pipeline "PipelineB" that I want to run upon completion of each build of PipelineA. That is set (again in the pipeline trigger settings) to be triggered by "Build completion", and I select the first Pipeline described above.
It also specifies the same branch filter for this triggering

[image]

Every night I get the following

01:00:00 PipelineA  (master)        took 1h

01:00:00 PipelineA  (release/v1.0)  took 1h

02:00:00 PipelineB  (master)

02:00:00 PipelineB  (master)  **<-- why?**

That is: the two PipelineA runs correctly trigger two runs of PipelineB. But the branch is "master" (the default branch) for both builds. I want it to run on the same branch as the triggering build used. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Share your YAML for your pipelines, specifically the `resource` section where you're defining your pipeline dependencies.

Comment: There is nothing relevant in the YAML. Both have `trigger: none` and the pipelines do not mention any pipeline/dependency/resource in YAML. The trigger dependency is configured only in the web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger settings on the PipelinesB do not affect the source branch for it. PipelineB will check out its repo and branch that is configured for it just after PipelineA completion on master or release/v1.0. You may try to get the source branch of the triggered pipeline and check out it on the target pipeline. Powershell example:

```
$token = "$(System.AccessToken)" 

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$orgUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
$teamProject = "$(System.TeamProject)"

$buildId = '$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)'

$buildUri = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds/$($buildId)?api-version=7.0"

function InvokeGetRequest ($GetUrl)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}

$result = InvokeGetRequest $buildUri

$srcbranch = $result.sourceBranch -replace "refs/heads/", ""

git checkout $srcbranch
```

Add it as the first step:

[image]

and do not forget to pass the token on the job level:

[image]